# How to add CSS to iframe content

Tags: jquery, css, iframe

Why this not working browsers except IE?

```
var head = jQuery("#frame1").contents().find("head");
var css = '<style type="text/css">' +
      '.container{background:blue}; ' +
      '</style>';
jQuery(head).append(css);     
});
```

Comment: What is the source of the `iframe`? Is it on the same domain?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that the iframe is on the same domain, as otherwise it wouldn't be working in IE.

Your problem is one of timing. You need to wait for the iframe to load, before you can apply your styles to it.

The way you do that is:

```
$('#frame1').load(function() { // Code to execute once iframe is loaded });
```

Once we know that it is loaded, we can apply any styles, thus:

```
var head = jQuery("#frame1").contents().find("head");
var css = '<style type="text/css">' + '.container{background:blue}; ' + '</style>';
$(head).append(css);
```

Although, you can shorten it to:

```
$('#frame1').load(function() {
  var css = '<style type="text/css">.container{background:blue};</style>';
  $('#frame1').contents().find("head").append(css);
});
```

This works for me in Firefox and Chrome (on a server stack - not locally, due to security restrictions).

Comment: Trying for 3 hours now, finally this works. Thank you Jack

Answer (score -1):

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function ($) {
     $('#mainFrame').load(function() {
      $('#mainFrame').contents().find("head").append($("<link/>", {
              rel: "stylesheet",
              href: "${ctx}/css/exp.css",
              type: "text/css"
         }));
     });
    });
</script>
```

```html
<iframe id="mainFrame" width="100%" height="auto"></iframe>
```